# Showing different windows 1 by 1

Tags: c++

I have a problem with my code. I want to show different windows one by one by clicking the "Next" button to show the next one like this:

```
int i = 0;
do {
    auto polyLines = new ExportPolyLines(nodeNames);
    polyLines->show();
    if (!polyLines->isVisible()) {
        i++;
    }
} while (i < 3);
```

The code compiled but did not work!
Can anyone help me about this?

Comment: You create an endless loop when `polyLines->isVisible()` returns true. And a memory leak.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that was the problem. I also tried the for loop but it shows all the windows at the same time:(

Comment: do you have any idea or example ? thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Like a wizard where you step through the pages?

Comment: Well seems like i fixed the problem.

Comment: if (_logIsSelected ) {
    // ui->bouton->setText("Next");
    for (int i = 0; i < _selectedWellLogs.size(); i++) {
     auto exportLogsData = new ExportsLogs(_selectedWellLogs[i], _wellLogsName[i], _folder);
     exportLogsData->exec();


    }

Comment: sorry for this mess, i am new in here. But I used qdialog in a for loop. So using the exec() function, the widgets will be shown one by one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an improvement to your comment I would suggest that you fix the memory leak.

```
if (_logIsSelected)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _selectedWellLogs.size(); i++)
    {
        auto exportLogsData = new ExportsLogs(_selectedWellLogs[i], _wellLogsName[i], _folder);
        exportLogsData->exec();

        delete exportLogsData; // Free the memory that has been used for ExportLogs
        exportLogsData = nullptr; // Not really necessary here, but good practice
    }
}
```

Comment: But just one question, isn't it done automatically by Qt when the window is closed? thanks

Comment: You can only rely on this of you pass a parent-level window as parent in the QDialog's or QWidget's constructor. However, as long as the parent window lives you would allocate more and more memory every time this function is called.